# My custom page.tpl.php file is not picked up

Tags: 7, theming

I have a site running in a subdir of my main site, like www.mysite.com/drupal.

I want to use a separate page.tpl.php file for my about page www.mysite.com/drupal/about.

I have tried naming the file page--about.tpl.php and page--drupal--about.tpl.php but neither is working. It just loads the regular page.tpl.php file.

This seems really straightforward and one of those should be correct. Is this buggy because Drupal is in a subdir or am I doing something wrong?

(And yes, I've cleared the cache.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you seen through your theme suggestions for the about page?

If not, then please refer to it and create a tpl file according to the suggestions and you will see that particular template running for "about" page.

As of Drupal 7.33, Drupal core has a `theme debug mode` that can be enabled and disabled via the `theme_debug` variable. Theme debug mode can be used to see possible template suggestions and the locations of template files right in your HTML markup (as HTML comments).

> To enable it, add this line to your settings.php:

```
$conf['theme_debug'] = TRUE;
```

> OR,
>   You can enable it with drush using:

```
drush vset theme_debug 1
```

> And disable using

```
drush vset theme_debug 0
```

**Note: You'll then see output like this when you inspect or view source:**

```
<!-- THEME DEBUG -->
<!-- CALL: theme('page') -->
<!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
   * page--front.tpl.php
   * page--node.tpl.php
   x page.tpl.php
-->
<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'modules/system/page.tpl.php' -->
…
<!-- END OUTPUT from 'modules/system/page.tpl.php' -->
```

Comment: This is a custom theme I'm making so no built in suggestions. I enabled theme_debug which did output some additional info but no references to any tpl.php files at all.

Comment: hmm... I enabled theme_debug in settings.php and cleared the caches but i'm not seeing any of that markup in the page source.

Comment: This is in Drupal 7.52 so it should be working. (theme_debug was already in the settings file, i just had to uncomment it.)

Comment: On which page are you inspecting the page source? Suggestions will be visible to you on about page. i am not sure why you are not able to see it.

Comment: I am looking at the about page, though I assume any page should be offering some suggestions once theme_debug is enabled. It doesn't appear on any pages.

Comment: FIXED. I hadn't made settings.php writable on the server so that was the theme_debug problem. Debug suggested page--node--9, so it doesn't seem to like the path alias 'about', which I have used on other sites with no problems. So, that's weird, but this is working so I'm calling it solved.